# Why am I getting a 'StopIteration' error when using mock's side effect?

Tags: python, mocking, side-effects

Please see below my function, which uses the function `Path`, which I am trying to mock out and use `side_effect` to assign a different value for two function calls.

```
def some_function(input_file, file): 
    compressed_file = Path(input_file)
    non_compressed_file = Path(file)



@mock.patch('exchanges.impl.bmex.preprocessing.Path')
def test_choose_MFII_files(mock_Path):
    mock_Path.side_effect = [Path(pd.jobserve_config[BMLL_SECTION][WORK_DIR]+ '/MDPRECVOLTICK_MC_20230703.ZIP'),
                              Path(pd.jobserve_config[BMLL_SECTION][WORK_DIR] + '/MERGED_MDPRECVOLTICK_MC_20230703.ZIP')]
```

When I run the above, I get:

```
_mock_self = <MagicMock name='Path' id='140495179866752'>, args = (PosixPath('/tmp'), 'MERGED_MDPRECVOLTICK_MC_20230703.ZIP'), kwargs = {}
self = <MagicMock name='Path' id='140495179866752'>, effect = <list_iterator object at 0x7fc7954ae220>

 def _execute_mock_call(_mock_self, *args, **kwargs):
        self = _mock_self
        # separate from _increment_mock_call so that awaited functions are
        # executed separately from their call, also AsyncMock overrides this method
    
        effect = self.side_effect
        if effect is not None:
            if _is_exception(effect):
                raise effect
            elif not _callable(effect):
>               result = next(effect)
E               StopIteration

../../anaconda3/envs/jobserveee/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mock/mock.py:1163: StopIteration
```

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: If you give an iterable to `side_effect`, it *"must yield a value on every call"*. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect In your tests, is the patched function called more than twice? If so, you'll get an error because your iterable has only two items.

Comment: Thank you my friend. It is called 3 times!